# Facebook Graph API does not return all of the events

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Not really sure what happened, but Facebook does not want to return all of the events for a group anymore. It is just returning one last one. The thing is that it was returning everything before, but now just one event. I don't know whether I changed somehing for the permissions or group settings..

Here's the Graph API query I have:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[group_id]/events?since=1349654400&fields=name,start_time,location,id,description,picture&access_token=[token]
```

I included a `since` parameter that goes back to 2012, but still only get 1 event.

If I go to the FB group page, I can see a list of the events, so they are there..

any idea why this is happening?

**EDIT:**

The FQL query does return all of the events:

```
SELECT eid, name, description, pic_big, start_time, end_time, location 
FROM event WHERE creator = [group_id]
```

Makes me even more confusing as to why graph API query is not working

Answer (score 0):

In the Graph API query, try using the `limit` parameter also.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you just need to tell graph-API that you want ALL the results. you may need to set the limit of returned results to a bigger number.

try this:

```
GET /v2.5/[group id]/events?limit=10000 HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
```

also, try changing both "since" and "until"